# Difference between OLEObjects and chart

Tags: vba, powerpoint

What is the difference between a chart that is linked to Excel and an OLEObject? I thought OLE = Object linking and embedding. My chart (which I thought is an object) is linked, so how is it not an OLEObject? In PPT one is labelled as a chart and the other (OLEObject) as an Object. I am confused.

Also, the line `MsgBox sh.OLEFormat.Object.Count` results in

> error 430

instead of returning the number of OLEObjects in my PPT Presentation. Why

```
 For Each Sl In pp.Slides
    For Each sh In Sl.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
           MsgBox sh.OLEFormat.Object.Count
        End If
     Next sh
 Next Sl
```

Comment: Also those two do not work:



1. For Each Sl In pp.Slides

Sl.Charts.Count
Next Sl



2. For Each Sl In pp.Slides

Sl.Shapes.Count
Next Sl

Comment: Please take a moment to read in the site's [help] about asking questions on Stack Overflow. Notice that a question should cover only **one** query, not multiple topics. For one thing, the site's goal is a Q&A repository: people should be able to identify whether or not a topic is relevant to their problem based on the title and a bit of text. Also, no single person may know the answer to multiple questions. Since you're supposed to mark *one* answer as "the" answer, that makes it difficult - another reason the site does not allow "broad" questions.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, was not aware of this. How were you able to post the code correctly? I tried it 1000x times and each time some of the code was outside the grey area :/

Comment: It's a problem with the combination bullets/numbering and code blocks. You need a "paragraph" of text with  no bullet/number in order for the code block to work correctly. I grind my teeth every time I run into it... <sigh> IN this case, it wasn't a problem because I wanted to make it not so obvious that your question covers two topics...

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of Microsoft Office (2007 and earlier) charts were, indeed, OLE objects, based on the Excel charting engine. A reference to the Excel object model was required in order to work with early binding.

Starting in Office 2010, with the introduction of new charting and graphics engines in the Microsoft Office suite, working with charts changed significantly. Among other things, the chart object model was "imported" into the various Office applications' object models, making a reference to an external library no longer necessary in order to work with charting functionality. The Office application object models now also have a `Chart` object.

All this is the case, even though creation and manipulation of charts is still done via the Excel application interface. (Indeed, it's not (no longer) possible to *hide* the Excel application when automating a chart.)

So, as far as the Office applications are concerned, Excel charts are now (for 8+ years) "native" parts of their object models and are no longer OLE objects.

```
sh.OLEFormat.Object.Count
```

returns an error because a single object does not have a `Count` property. The code is not querying `Count` on a collection of `Shapes`, only on the single `Shape` object. You'd need a variable to add up the number of times the loop encounters a `msoLinkedOLEObject` (something like `i = i + 1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x as Long 
Dim y as Long
For Each Sl In pp.Slides
    For Each sh In Sl.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
           x = x + 1
        End If
     Next sh
     ' Show how many OLE objects on this slide
     MsgBox Cstr(x) & " OLE objects on Slide " & Cstr(Sl.SlideIndex)
     y = y + x
 Next Sl
 ' Show total OLE objects in presentation
 MsgBox Cstr(y) & " OLE objects in presentation"
```

If you want to count *embedded* (type msoEmbeddedOLEObject) as well as linked charts, you'll need to adjust the code. And as Cindy has pointed out, the charts might be "PowerPoint-native" charts (type msoChart) with no connection to Excel.

Comment: @Cindy Meister: You are absolute machine, or rather master (Meister is German for Master, but you probably already new that :D) 

Thanks so much! The backround information you gave me is so impressive!

My own lack of knowledge leads me to some follow-up questions, though. I hope that is fine, but of course I don't expect to answer everything, since you already took so much time to answer me comprehensivley.

anyways here some questions regarding your answer:

1.In Case a chart is an OLE, does that mean, that the chart contains an OLE, or that it is an Object type of its own?

Comment: 2. What do you refer to, when you say "external" library?
3. Regarding the error: The first part I understood, but why does the 

For Each Sl In pp.Slides Sl.Charts.Count Next Sl 

not work? I am not referring to the number of charts in each slide?

4. Since I am new here: Is it possible to "upvote" your post or something like that?

5. Do you give tutoring / private courses in VBA? I would defintely book a session :)

Kind regards
Michael

Comment: Also how can I add paragraphs in the comments? It is so bad to read like this, sry

Comment: Steven: Thanks also I have to check out the code first. But I think I also have one follow-up question, if that is alright

Comment: @Underhook32 Follow-up questions are fine. And to upvote Cindy's post, click the little upward pointing triangle next to it (though depending on your reputation, this might or might not appear ... I don't really know). Paragraphs in comments: I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: @ Steve: Thanks for replying! I upvoted the comments of the both of you!

The follow-up questions for you would be: You wrote: "[...] pointed out, the charts might be "PowerPoint-native" charts (type msoChart) with no connection to Excel."   

Here is the thing that confuses me. The chart I am talking about DOES have a connection to Excel (by which I mean, that chart depends on data input in Excel) and is addressed with "msochart". So we are not talking about the same thing or on other words, that chart would not be "Power-Point native" but is also not an OLEObject?

Kind regards
Mike

Comment: @Underhook32 If in doubt, check the .Type property of the selected shape. If it's 3, then it's a native PPT chart. If 7, it's an Embedded OLE object, if 10, a Linked OLE object